# Fine sorting array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that represent hockey rank data:

```
[
  {
     name: "Russia",
     points: 10,
     iihf: 1
  },
  {
     name: "USA",
     points: 10,
     iihf: 7
  },
  {
     name: "Slovakia",
     points: 8,
     iihf: 6
  }
]
```

I want to sort the data descending from the highest score. If two or more teams share the same point count, they have to be fine sorted using next dimensions, namely the IIHF rank (ascending order). Is there an elegant solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you tried/searched?

Comment: I find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9175783/989121) quite elegant ;]

Comment: @thg435 - possibly because it's your own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript sort function. Sort by First then by Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175268/javascript-sort-function-sort-by-first-then-by-second)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I've done a simple fn as sort param that sorted by dimension name, but couldn't wrap my head around how to keep the original sort intact while fine sorting the equals. Thought I had to extract the equals, sort those, and put them back into the original sort. Didn't know if I could do it in a less elaborate way, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.sort()`, if the values of `points` are equal, sort on `iihf` instead

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.points == b.points) return a.iihf > b.iihf ? 1 : -1;    
    return a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c83x4/)

Answer (score 2):

As addition: if you know an upper limit of the iihf score, you can also precompute a compound score, that you only use for sorting. The compound score could look like this:

```
obj.cscore = obj.points * 10000 + obj.iihf;
```

After that, you can just sort after the cscore:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return a.cscore - b.cscore;
});
```

If you don't want to pollute your original objects, you can use a temporary map (as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)):

```
var map = arr.map(function (e, i) {
    return {index: i, cscore: e.points * 1000 + e.iihf};
});

map.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.cscore - b.cscore;
});

var result = map.map(function(e){
  return arr[e.index]
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M48GD/)**

Comment: `return a.cscore < b.cscore ? 1 : -1` is not correct - you're missing the equal case. An elegant way to compare numbers is to return their difference: `return a.score - b.score`.

Comment: @thg435 thx, you're right. I actually mindlessly copied this part from the answer of adeneo (which also doesn't return zero). Anyway, I fixed it.

Comment: Great! Now the next step: since both sort fields are numbers, you can combine them using boolean or: `return b.points - a.points || a.iihf - b.iihf` - no need for a compound key.

Comment: @thg435 that's a really beautiful and simple way to solve this problem. Why didn't you post it as an answer? My goal was to introduce the general concept of a compound key. I realize that in this particular case, it might not be necessary but it is a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, schwartzian transform is useful technique worth knowing about. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function comparator(a, b) {
   if (a.points == b.points) return a.iihf > b.iihf ? 1 : -1;    
return a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1;
}

var json = { "homes": 
             [
  {
     name: "Russia",
     points: 10,
     iihf: 1
  },
  {
     name: "USA",
     points: 10,
     iihf: 7
  },
  {
     name: "Slovakia",
     points: 8,
     iihf: 6
  }
]};
console.log(json["homes"].sort(comparator));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nt3yL/10/)