# Knockout.js table sorting by value and alphabetical

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

I have a table of data and I've set up a knockout binding handler that will sort the data of the table when clicking on a . I can sort by the value but the issue is when a group of data is the same value I need the table to then sort that grouping alphabetically by the name column.  Here is the knockout (in typescript):

```
ko.bindingHandlers["sort"] = {
    init: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) => {
        var ascending = false;
        element.onclick = () => {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var array = value.arrayName;
            var key = value.key;
            ascending = !ascending;

            array.sort(function (first, last) {
                var left = first;
                var right = last;
                if (!ascending) {
                    left = last;
                    right = first;
                }
                var keys = key.split('.');
                for (var i in keys) {
                    var keyName = keys[i];
                    var parentIndex = keyName.indexOf('()');
                    if (parentIndex > 0) {
                        keyName = keyName.substring(0, parentIndex);
                        left = left[keyName]();
                        right = right[keyName]();
                    } 
                    else {
                        left = left[keyName];
                        right = right[keyName];
                    }
                 }
                 return left == right ? 0 : left < right ? -1 : 1;
                });
            };
        }
    };
}
```

And my table HTML:

```
<table class="table" id="largeTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-bind="sort: { arrayName: product, key: 'name' }">Name</th>
        <th data-bind="sort: { arrayName: product, key: 'type' }">Type</th>
        <th data-bind="sort: { arrayName: product, key: 'reviewsNumber()' }">Reviews</th>
        <th data-bind="sort: { arrayName: product, key: 'ratingNumber()' }">Ratings</th>
        <th data-bind="sort: { arrayName: product, key: 'priceNumber()' }">Price</th>
        <th data-bind="sort: { arrayName: product, key: 'date' }">Date</th>
        <th data-bind="sort: { arrayName: product, key: 'status' }">Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: productOnPage -->
    <tr>
        <td><div data-bind="text: name"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: type"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: reviews"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: rating"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: price"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: date"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: status"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

If I have ten products that all have a 4 star rating then I would want the table to sort those ten by the name attribute.  How can I do this?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175268/javascript-sort-function-sort-by-first-then-by-second.

Comment: Excellent!  I was able to integrate the top answer from there to make this work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update I made to get this to work:

```
ko.bindingHandlers["sort"] = {
init: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) => {
    var ascending = false;
    element.onclick = () => {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var array = value.arrayName;
        var key = value.key;
        ascending = !ascending;

        array.sort(function (first, last) {
            var left = first;
            var right = last;

            var leftName = first.name;
            var rightName = last.name;

            if (!ascending) {
                left = last;
                right = first;
            }
            var keys = key.split('.');
            for (var i in keys) {
                var keyName = keys[i];
                var parentIndex = keyName.indexOf('()');
                if (parentIndex > 0) {
                    keyName = keyName.substring(0, parentIndex);
                    left = left[keyName]();
                    right = right[keyName]();
                } 
                else {
                    left = left[keyName];
                    right = right[keyName];
                }
             }

             if (left > right ) {
                 return 1;
             }
             else if (left  < right ) {
                 return -1;
             }

             if (leftName < rightName) {
                 return -1;
             }
             else if (leftName > rightName) {
                 return 1;
             }
             else { 
                 return 0;
             }
            });
        };
    }
};
```

}