# Sortying array by two criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array like this:

```
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    date: 591020824000,
    isImportant: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: 591080224000,
    isImportant: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: 591080424000,
    isImportant: true,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    date: 591080225525,
    isImportant: false,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    date: 591020225525,
    isImportant: true,
  },
];
```

And I'm trying to sort this array so elements that are isImportant: true with the most recent date are displayed first and then elements that have isImportant:false with the most recent date

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Try to split this into 2 arrays, one for important items one for not, then sort each of them by date, then join them into single sorted array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript sort function. Sort by First then by Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175268/javascript-sort-function-sort-by-first-then-by-second)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.isImportant && !b.isImportant)
        return -1;
    if(!a.isImportant && b.isImportant)
        return 1;
    return b.date-a.date;
});
```

I hope this will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
array.sort((a,b)=>{
    if(a.isImportant==b.isImportant){
        return b.date-a.date;
    }else{
        return a.isImportant?-1:1;
    }
})
```

[duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129952/javascript-sort-array-by-two-fields)