# How can I sort an array alphabetticaly and by length

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

Assume I have this arrray: ['a', 'c', 'bb', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'aa'].
I want to sort it in this way:

aaa, aa, a, bbb, bb, c.

```
this.array= this.array.sort((n1, n2) => n1.localeCompare(n2));
this.array= this.array.sort((n1, n2) => n2.length - n1.length);
```

But this is not right. How can I fix it?

Comment: After first sort, add another sort by length? `.sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length);` :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript sort function. Sort by First then by Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175268/javascript-sort-function-sort-by-first-then-by-second)

Comment: @HalilÇakar that will just sort the array by length of each string.

Comment: `sort` mutates the array. So, there is no need to reassign: `this.array = this.array.sort(...)`

Comment: @adiga right yea i really didn't think of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if one string starts with the other and take the delta of the length as return value.

```js
var array = ['a', 'c', 'bb', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'aa'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    let d = a.startsWith(b) || b.startsWith(a)
            ? b.length - a.length
            : 0;

    return d || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(array);
```

Without [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```js
var array = ['a', 'c', 'bb', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'aa'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    let min = Math.min(a.length, b.length),
        d = a.slice(0, min) === b.slice(0, min)
            ? b.length - a.length
            : 0;

    return d || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I don't know by default if in my array I have characters 'a' or 'b'. It's just an example.. it's a dynamic array

Comment: just try with you dynamic content.

Comment: strange.. it says me a.startsWith is not a function. I also explicit a:string, b:string

Comment: @travis_91 you could use square bracket notation `arr.sort((a, b) => a[0] == b[0] ? b.length - a.length : a.localeCompare(b))`

Comment: you could take a [polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.startsWith) for [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: no I did a wrong thing.. fixed. It's work like a charm!! thank you very much