# Javascript: sort an array of objects with a first attribute , and when equal sort with another

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

i ve an array which looks like this :

```
let myarray = 
[{id:1 , name: "mark" , birthday: "1990-08-18"},
{id:2 , name: "fred" , birthday: "1990-08-17"},
{id:3 , name: "franck" , birthday: "1990-08-16"},
{id:4 , name: "mike" , birthday: "1990-08-15"},
{id:5 , name: "jean" , birthday: "1990-08-17"}]
```

i'm sorting thos object by "**birthday**"

```
myarray.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.birthday).getTime() - new Date(a.birthday).getTime());
```

but sometimes , i ve the same birthday value for two objects (birthday is equal) ,
in that case **i want that the sort compares those two objects** (not all the objects) **with the higher** "**id**" (which have the higher id is prior)

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: [Javascript sort function. Sort by First then by Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175268/javascript-sort-function-sort-by-first-then-by-second/9175302)

Comment: btw, with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates, you could sort with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a separate case in the `sort` function as follows:

```js
let myarray = [
{id:1 , name: "mark" , birthday: "1990-08-18"},
{id:2 , name: "fred" , birthday: "1990-08-17"},
{id:3 , name: "franck" , birthday: "1990-08-16"},
{id:4 , name: "mike" , birthday: "1990-08-15"},
{id:5 , name: "jean" , birthday: "1990-08-17"}
]

myarray.sort((a, b) => {
     let dif = new Date(b.birthday).getTime() - new Date(a.birthday).getTime();
     if(dif != 0) return dif;
     else return b.id - a.id;
});
console.log(myarray);
```